# What is this red clock coming in front of Java classes in VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm making a Spring Boot application using VSCode, but there is a red clock symbol in front of Java classes and the autocomplete feature is not working.
I've already installed all the required extensions for Spring Boot development and also Java extension pack by Microsoft.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the symbol?

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it's not the Java icon VSCode uses ?

I noticed it looks like a clock, but it's actually a J letter (not very round) in a red circle.

[image: java file tab in VSCode]
(picture courtesy of VSCode issue [change java icon to the java cup icon](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78421) on GitHub)

Answer (score -1):

If you mean this red clock[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC4oI.png)

you can remove it by clicking with your right mouse tap on src, then go to mark directory as and then to sourses root. Then your programme will work again. :)